# How do I read a local file in my ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

If I want to read a local file from my project, given a relative path from the project directory, how could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using ApplicationBasePath  from PlatformServices.ApplicationEnvironment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get absolute path in ASP.Net Core alternative way for Server.MapPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992261/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-asp-net-core-alternative-way-for-server-mappath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `ApplicationBasePath` from `PlatformServices.ApplicationEnvironment`. This will make it possible to resolve non-absolute paths relative to your application base path.

Answer (score 3):

Now that .NET Core has [RTM-ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_to_manufacturing_(RTM)), you need to use `IHostingEnvironment` instead. It exposes `WebRootPath`and `ContentRootPath`.

Comment: `IHostingEnvironment` is obsolete. use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment