# How to get absolute path in ASP.Net Core alternative way for Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to get absolute path in ASP net core alternative way for **`Server.MapPath`**

I have tried to use **`IHostingEnvironment`** but it doesn't give proper result.

```
IHostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment();
var str1 = env.ContentRootPath; // Null
var str2 = env.WebRootPath; // Null, both doesn't give any result
```

I have one image file (Sample.PNG) in *wwwroot* folder I need to get this absolute path.

Comment: Inject it as a dependency into the dependent class. the framework will populate it for you.

Comment: Is there a way to inject the IHostingEnvironment dependency if we are manually creating our own classes outside of the Owin pipeline?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As of .Net Core v3.0, it should be [`IWebHostEnvironment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment) to access the `WebRootPath` which has been moved to the web specific environment interface.

Inject `IWebHostEnvironment` as a dependency into the dependent class. The framework will populate it for you

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _hostEnvironment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        string path = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Sample.PNG");
        return View();
    }
}
```

You could go one step further and create your own path provider service abstraction and implementation.

```
public interface IPathProvider {
    string MapPath(string path);
}

public class PathProvider : IPathProvider {
    private IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;

    public PathProvider(IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
        _hostEnvironment = environment;
    }

    public string MapPath(string path) {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, path);
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

And inject `IPathProvider` into dependent classes.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    private IPathProvider pathProvider;

    public HomeController(IPathProvider pathProvider) {
        this.pathProvider = pathProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        string path = pathProvider.MapPath("Sample.PNG");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Make sure to register the service with the DI container

```
services.AddSingleton<IPathProvider, PathProvider>();
```

Comment: Important sentence here is **The framework will populate it for you**. So just adding a dependency is enough.

Answer (score 15):

#### .NET Core 3.0

Var 1:

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Var 2:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("\\bin"));
```

Comment: Var 2 is the correct answer (well without the substring part). Just plain AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is good. The problem with all the answers around web content root is that when you run in local debug it is resolved to the the source folder not the compiled debug folder. This makes a big difference if you have post build events copying things to the output folder that do not exist in the source folder.

Answer (score 10):

*** Hack ***
Not recommended, but FYI you can get an absolute path from a relative path with

`var abs = Path.GetFullPath("~/Content/Images/Sample.PNG").Replace("~\\","");`

Prefer the DI/Service approaches above, but if you are in a non-DI situation (e.g., a class instantiated with `Activator`) this will work.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I needed to save some data to file (not accesible to user) to my asp.net core app from static method in static class and this saved me.

Comment: I have a reflection scenario (Activator), so this saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is to use the `IFileProvider.GetFileInfo()` method.

```
    public IActionResult ResizeCat([FromServices] IFileProvider fileProvider)
    {
        // get absolute path (equivalent to MapPath)
        string absolutePath = fileProvider.GetFileInfo("/assets/images/cat.jpg").PhysicalPath;  
        ... 
    }
```

You must register `IFileProvider` [like this to be able to access it through DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        var physicalProvider = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider;
        var embeddedProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        var compositeProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(physicalProvider, embeddedProvider);

        // choose one provider to use for the app and register it
        //services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);
        //services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(embeddedProvider);
        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(compositeProvider);
    }
```

As you can see this logic (for where a file comes from) can get quite complex, but your code won't break if it changes.

You can create a custom `IFileProvider` with `new PhysicalFileProvider(root)` if you have some special logic. I had a situation where I want to load an image in middleware, and resize or crop it. But it's an Angular project so the path is different for a deployed app. The middleware I wrote takes `IFileProvider` from `startup.cs` and then I could just use `GetFileInfo()` like I would have used `MapPath` in the past.

Comment: _hostingEnvironment is not defined. Where does it come from?

Comment: For completeness, @JimS, IHostingEnvironment is injected by the framework if you have a constructor parameter of that type. _hostingEnvironment is the field in the controller class set to the IHostingEnvironment

Comment: Thanks for adding that. I guess I missed putting it in but you can see it in Nkosi’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are accessing it from Startup/Program routines, it is available under `WebApplicationBuilder.Environment` e.g.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var webRootPath = builder.Environment.WebRootPath;

        ConfigureServices(builder);

        ...
 }
```