# Serving a file through a middleware NuGet package in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

I am currently working in a large enterprise environment. We are looking for a way to put ASP.NET Core applications offline in a streamlined way for all development teams.

My solution was to build & distribute a NuGet package on our local NuGet feed. It allows users to pass a key which translates to a `true` or `false` value in the `appSettings` file. I am currently struggling to read the HTML file and serve it.

```
public class OfflinePageMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly string _appSettingsParameterKey;

    public OfflinePageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string appSettingsParameterKey)
    {
        _next = next;
        _appSettingsParameterKey = appSettingsParameterKey;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_appSettingsParameterKey))
        {
            var setting = configuration[_appSettingsParameterKey];

            var parseSucceeded = bool.TryParse(setting, out var goOffline);

            if (parseSucceeded && goOffline)
            {
                // Return offline HTTP page
                await ReturnOfflinePageAsync(context);
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }

    private static async Task ReturnOfflinePageAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(
                Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "wwwroot/application-offline.html"));

        byte[] buffer;

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

            buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("File not found.");
        }

        context.Response.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        using (var stream = context.Response.Body)
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

When adding the NuGet package to an arbitrary ASP.NET Core application, it always returns `File not found`.

The Build Action of my application-offline.html is set to `Content`.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit with screenshots:**

When I look in my Solution Explorer, I can see the file after installing the NuGet package. But when I take a look in Windows Explorer, the file is not physically present in the wwwroot folder.

Do I maybe have to take a different approach to include the file?

[image: SolutionExplorer]

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992261/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-asp-net-core-alternative-way-for-server-mappath

Comment: @ste-fu I have edited my question. When I replace the code with `hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath`, it's still not found, because the file is not physically present in the wwwroot folder.

Comment: Applications using the new csproj format link to the content elements in your packages directory, rather than copying them into your project. I can't remember how to include them in your build output off the top of my head