# .net core 2.2 site looks files on wrong path

Tags: asp.net-core

I am doing maintenance to a .net core 2.2 application. On several computers it works perfectly, but when I publish it to the server where it should be it gives error in all references to a file. Example: File.ReadAllText ("./App/Config.json").

The problem is that it looks for the file in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv..., instead of looking for it in the folder where the site is published. This generates errors like:

Could not find a part of the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\App\Config.json'.

of course the site is published in c:\inetpub\wwwroot[sitename]

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Using relative paths is subject to such issues here and there. You have to modify that application to resolve full paths, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992261/how-to-get-absolute-path-in-asp-net-core-alternative-way-for-server-mappath/43992313

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths is not good practice on server side code.

What you should use instead is [IWebHostEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and it's property `WebRootPath`

To access that you can do it inside your controller like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public MyController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        foreach(string filePath in Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath))
        {
            string file = filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

If you do not want to inject it like this or you need to access in out of controller inside `Startup.cs` add `public static IWebHostEnvironment _env` and edit this:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _env = env;
}
```

and now you can access it from anywhere with `Startup._env`