# How do I read in a file from disc during runtime in my WebAPI .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

In my solution I have a file called *beep.png* directly in the root, right next to *Startup.cs* file. I changed its properties to *always copy*. I activated *UseFileServer* and opted in to browse the directory structure to be sure.

However, when I run the code `Image.FromFile("beep.png");`, I only get the error that the file isn't found.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>     Message=C:\Program Files\IIS Express\beep.png

How can I enable the file to be accessible?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491474/2309376). The question is similar to yours, you just need to know what the relative path is to the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `IWebHostEnvirounment` to get the root content path (technicaly the project folder), or to get the web root path (the wwwroot folder under project folder).

`_hostingEnvirounment.ContentRootPath` will return:

> D:\Hosting\ProjectFolder

`_hostingEnvirounment.WebRootPath` will rturn:

> D:\Hosting\ProjectFolder\wwwroot

So in your case; inject `IWebHostEnvirounment` to your controller then get the content root folder as below:

```
public class MyApiController : ControllerBase {

    private readonly IWebHostEnvirounment _hostingEnvirounment;

    public MyApiController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    // get image from project root folder \ProjectFolder\
    public Image GetImageFromContentRoot(string name) {

        // e.g.: imgPath = "D:\\Hosting\\ProjectFolder\\beep.png"
        var imgPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvirounment.ContentRootPath, name);

        return Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    }

    //get image from projects wwwroot folder
     public Image GetImageFromWebRoot(string name) {

        // e.g.: imgPath = "D:\\Hosting\\ProjectFolder\\wwwroot\\beep.png"
        var imgPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvirounment.WebRootPath, name);

        return Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: `IHostingEnvironment` is obsolete. use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment