# How can I get the root of my project in ASP.NET and not the location of IIS Express using .CurrentDirectory()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, litedb

I have an ASP.NET Core project that I'm developing and I'm making use of LiteDB as a database solution. In order to instantiate my database I need to provide a URI so that the program knows where to create the database.

Usually I'd do something like `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory()` to find the current directory I'm in and modify that, however the result of this command turns out to be `C:\program files\IIS Express` or something similar. Basically the current directory points to the location of IIS Express.

Instead I want to get the root of my ASP.NET project, the location that contains my controllers folder, appsettings.json, bin and obj folders.

What command do I need to use to get a string representing this location? I don't want to use a hard coded string for obvious reasons.

Comment: have you tried injecting `IHostingEnvirounment` https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341264/5519026

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to DI you could try:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

If you have access to DI, try this:

Inject the `IHostingEnvironment` and call `environment.ContentRootPath`

[How to get root directory of project in asp.net core. Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() doesn't seem to work correctly on a mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709657/how-to-get-root-directory-of-project-in-asp-net-core-directory-getcurrentdirect)

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served by using a dedicated location (such as a network share) rather than the folder that contains the executable code. Having user data mixed into deployed code comes with a lot of headaches:

- Deployments become more complex as they need to account for the presence of user data. This is especially true if you need to delete pre-existing code during a deployment.
- If the user data is sensitive, developers may be denied access to read the deployed code. This can make troubleshooting issues much harder.
- Backups of deployed code will contain user data, which means they will always appear to be different even if nothing (code-wise) has changed.

Of course, this all assumes that the production environment is configured differently from developers' local machines.